# fast merge(..., all = TRUE) with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Is is possible to make the equivalent of a merge(..., all = TRUE) with the data.table syntax (like X[Y]) ?

Specifically, I would need a very fast way of getting the result of:

```
item_length = data.table(index = 1:10, length =  c(2,5,4,6,3),key ="index")
item_weigth = data.table(index = c(2,4,6,7,8,11), weight= c(.3,.5,.2), key = "index")
merge(x2,y2, all=TRUE)
```

Which is :

```
> merge(item_length ,item_weigth , all=TRUE)
      index length weight
[1,]     1      2     NA
[2,]     2      5    0.3
[3,]     3      4     NA
[4,]     4      6    0.5
[5,]     5      3     NA
[6,]     6      2    0.2
[7,]     7      5    0.3
[8,]     8      4    0.5
[9,]     9      6     NA
[10,]    10      3     NA
[11,]    11     NA    0.2
```

Comment: `merge.data.table` should be pretty fast. Can you provide some timings?  We have improved its speed in recent versions. Which version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: Ok, I've updated to the latest version 1.8.0 and it is actually extremely fast! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I think this is worth sharing:

A very fast solution seems to be to update to the latest version of data.table (1.8.0). 
(Thank you so much, Matthew !)

Here is my test data and benchmark results:

With data.table:

```
full_index <- 1:5000000
ratio_in_samples <- 0.8
x <- data.table(index = sample(full_index, length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples), 
                var1 = rnorm(length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples),
                key = "index")

y <- data.table(index = sample(full_index, length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples), 
                var2 = rnorm(length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples),
                key = "index")

system.time(
result <- merge(x,y, all=TRUE)
)
```

Time with data.table:

```
user  system elapsed 
5.05    0.55    5.62
```

Whereas with data.frame:

```
full_index <- 1:5000000
ratio_in_samples <- 0.8
x <- data.frame(index = sample(full_index, length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples), 
                var1 = rnorm(length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples))

y <- data.frame(index = sample(full_index, length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples), 
                var2 = rnorm(length(full_index)*ratio_in_samples))

system.time(
  result <- merge(x,y, all=TRUE)
)
```

Time with data.frame:

```
user  system elapsed 
78.83    1.75   80.67
```

Comment: Can it be done even faster?

Comment: There is, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77324984/13460602

Answer (score 2):

[`collapse`](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/index.html) has a very fast `join` function. With the 5M rows data.frame provided by @nassimhddd, `collapse` is 2.5x faster than `data.table`:

Benchmark:

```r
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
#        dt 1745.0900 2414.042 2598.093 2543.145 2837.262 3450.925
#  collapse  937.0518 1006.102 1076.427 1014.616 1071.268 1353.097
```

---

Code

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
  dt = merge(x, y, all = TRUE),
  collapse = join(x, y, how = "full"),
  times = 5L
)
```

Comment: ‘collapse’ looks like a very interesting package. Shame the API is so atrocious.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I'm really a fan of it. I don't think the API is so bad, e.g. compared to data.table